# How do i boot into my original os?

Tags: grub

I installed Android-x86 alongside mx-linux, and entrusted grub is only showing the Android-x86 boot options.

How do I boot into Linux again?

Comment: Can you provide a picture?

Comment: I feel pain. How can I restore my health?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend booting [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) from a USB thumb drive. The software searches your system for bootable operating systems (and existing but inactive bootloader configurations).

Answer (score -1):

Normally windows is on NTFS formatted drive and im guessing your linux is on ext4 or lvm version of drive formatting. Since the two are so different im fairly sure ya just need to go into your bios menu and change your boot order or find the menu that will give you the option of what drive/partition your original is on. I hope that helps a little bit

Comment: This answer assumes multiple hard-drives and file-systems which are not even mentioned in the question.